# NotifyIcon remains in Tray even after application closing but disappears on Mouse Hover

Tags: c#, notifyicon

There are many questions on SO asking same doubt.
Solution for this is to set

`notifyIcon.icon = null` and calling `Dispose` for it in FormClosing event.

In my application, there is no such form but has Notification icon which updates on Events.
On creation, I hide my form and make `ShowInTaskbar` property `false`. Hence I can not have a "FormClosing" or "FormClosed" events.

If this application gets event to exit, It calls `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` to exit.

I have added `notifyIcon.icon = null` as well as Dispose before killing, but still icon remains taskbar until I hover mouse over it.

**EDIT**: If I assume that this behaviour is due to calling `GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`, Is there any elegant way to exit from application which will clear all resources and remove icon from system tray.

Comment: Time to accept an answer don't you think :D Let me suggest you the one of "The Muffin Man" :D

Comment: @Nudity Problem is I just got rid of that notify icon... And now I don't have that code to verify any solution :-)

Comment: Will I just did :D and the Dispose() fixed it :D

Comment: One option is to refresh the traybar after killing the process, see the posts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311877/tray-icon-does-not-disappear-on-killing-process and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703983/update-redraw-system-tray-window-after-a-button-is-removed for details

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was to use the Closed event and hide and dispose of the icon.

```
icon.BalloonTipClosed += (sender, e) => { 
                                            var thisIcon = (NotifyIcon)sender;
                                            thisIcon.Visible = false;
                                            thisIcon.Dispose(); 
                                        };
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ... `Dispose()` is what you need there !

Comment: what is this called? += (sender, e) => { // code };

Comment: @user3365695 It's a lambda expression. Check this link out with examples of the 3 ways to specify the delegate https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I remember when I was learning delegates were not explained well. A delegate is simply a way to provide the name of a method to be invoked later by something. You can use any method you've made that matches the signature the event expects. In this case we register a method to be called once the Balloon tip internally invokes the `BalloonTipClosed` event. In this example, syntactically we don't provide the name of a method, we define what's called an anonymous function/method. This is a newer code feature which is why you see multiple ways to do it notably `delegate(string s) {//code}`.

Comment: Application.Exit(); NotifyIcon = null; works every time on multiple "windows reinstalls" - seperate issue lol

Answer (score 55):

You can either set

```
notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
```

OR

```
notifyIcon.Icon = null;
```

in the form closing event.

Comment: Does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Gigi Did you try it ?

Comment: I did with WPF NotifyIcon.

Comment: works for me in WPF. You must do it before closing the application though

Comment: `icon.BalloonTipClosed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var thisIcon = (NotifyIcon)sender;
                    thisIcon.Visible = false;
                    thisIcon.Dispose();
                };`

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: This is genious! Solved my problem just as I wanted to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheMuffinMan mayhaps you want to make that an answer

Comment: @DennisChristian I made it an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thx :) Work fine :)

Comment: For those that will fall on this answer it is important to note that this DOES fix the issue. If your icon stays it's because you are debugging (not all PC does that but we have 2 out of 11 that does it here). If you run the exe the icon will in fact disappear.

Answer (score 18):

Components just must be disposed in the right order like this :

```
NotifyIcon.Icon.Dispose();

NotifyIcon.Dispose();
```

Add this to the `MainWindow` closing event.

Hope this will help.

Comment: i think that perhaps it's important to note that stopping debugging doesn't trigger override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e), disposing will not be triggerd

Answer (score 12):

Use this code when you want to do it when you press the Exit or Close button:

```
private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon.Dispose();
    Application.Exit(); // or this.Close();
}
```

Use this code when you want to do it when the form is closing:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon.Dispose();
    Application.Exit(); // or this.Close();
}
```

The important code is this:

```
notifyIcon.Dispose();
```

Comment: I tried the following code and it worked.  private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mNotifyIcon.Dispose();
        }

Answer (score 11):

Use `notifyIcon.Visible = False` in `FormClosing` event

Comment: To do a _clean_ cleanup you still should call `notifyIcon.Dispose()`. When your class doesn't have a function wehre you could call this, you should implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Not sure why this is not marked as the answer but it fixed my issue as well...thanks @Ismael

Comment: @KevinMoore because the OP explicitly stated that he has no `Form` on which they could handle the `FormClosing` event

Answer (score 4):

The only way that works to me was:

1. On design screen changing notifyicon1 property visible=false
2. Insert the code below on main form "activated" event:

```
NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
```

3. Insert the code below on main form "closing" event:

```
NotifyIcon1.Visible = false
NotifyIcon1.Icon.Dispose()
NotifyIcon1.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour, unfortunately; it's due to the way Windows works. You can'r really do anything about it.

See [Issue with NotifyIcon not dissappearing on Winforms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067844/issue-with-notifyicon-not-dissappearing-on-winforms-app) for some suggestions, but none of them ever worked for me.

Also see [Notify Icon stays in System Tray on Application Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980029/notify-icon-stays-in-system-tray-on-application-close)

Microsoft have marked this as "won't fix" on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: i feel like windows has been doing this forever.

Comment: OSX will often leave a GAP in the task bar in similar situation, just a quirk i guess of how both OSes draw their task / menu bars.

Comment: Isn't there any elegant way to Exit from this process instead of "GetCurrentProcess.Kill()" and Will that change my this behaviour?

Comment: It could! I feel like the fact you are killing it, is what is causing some of the issue. You could try waiting for the next run loop before killing, after your set the icon nil and disposing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Can you provide me any link where it says "Won't fix"?

Comment: I guess there must be some fix for this - utorrent for example has also icon in system tray. But, when it exits, the icon disapears.

Comment: This is normal behavior, but you can get around it. See answers about NotifyIcon.Visible

Answer (score 2):

I don't think WPF has it's own NotifyIcon, does it? If you're using the 3rd party Harcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification, then try this:

In order to prevent my app from closing when the window is closed (run in background), I separated the logic for closing the window (hitting the x button in the upper right) and actually shutting it down (through the context menu). To make this work, make your context menu set `_isExplicitClose` to true. Otherwise, it'll just hide the window and continue to run.

What this does is, on explicit close, hide tray icon and the form before closing. This way the icon isn't hanging around after the application is shutdown.

```
private bool _isExplicitClose;
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);

    if (!_isExplicitClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}

protected void QuitService(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _isExplicitClose = true;
   TaskbarIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
   Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Application.DoEvents();` after setting `notifyIcon.Icon` to `null` and disposing:

```
notifyIcon.Icon = null;
notifyIcon.Dispose();
Application.DoEvents();
```

And consider `Environment.Exit(0);` instead of `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`.

Answer (score 1):

i can tell you can solve the problem simply using the .dispose() method, but that is not called if you kill the process instead of exit the application.

please refer to [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms157894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you have built a simple Windows Form application else refer to [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is more general.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these and none of them worked for me.  After thinking about it for a while I realized that the application creating the "balloon" was exiting before it had a chance to actually dispose of the balloon.  I added a while loop just before `Application.Exit()` containing an `Application.DoEvents()` command.  This allowed my `NotifyIcon1_BalloonTipClosed` to actually finish disposing of the icon before exiting.

```
while (notifyIcon1.Visible)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
Application.Exit();
```

And the tip closed method: (You need to include the `thisIcon.visible = false` in order for this to work)

```
private void NotifyIcon1_BalloonTipClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thisIcon = (NotifyIcon)sender;
    thisIcon.Icon = null;
    thisIcon.Visible = false;
    thisIcon.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you.

The proper way are send WM_CLOSE message to a process.
I use the c# code I found in this article.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82992842-80eb-43c8-a9e6-0a6a1d19b00f/terminating-a-process-in-a-friendly-way

Answer (score 0):

edit codes of ...Designer.cs as below coding.

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
           {
           if (disposing )
               {
               this.notifyicon.Dispose();
               }
           base.Dispose(disposing);
           }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make any one of the other solutions work. It turned out to be kind of a hybrid of all the above! I hunted and pecked until I had a consistently working solution both in debug and in EXE execution modes! I have no idea why MSFT would mark this as "Not going to fix"? I wish I had that liberty!

```
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //THIS CODE IS CRAZY BUT MUST BE DONE IN ORDER TO PROPERLY REMOVE THE SYSTEM TRAY ICON!
        //GREAT ARTICLE ON THIS ON STACK OVERFLOW
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723843/notifyicon-remains-in-tray-even-after-application-closing-but-disappears-on-mous

        //BTW THIS IS KIND OF A BLEND OF ALL THE SOLUTIONS BECAUSE I COULD NOT FIND A SINGLE SOLUTION THAT WOULD WORK!
        systray_icon.Visible = false;
        while (systray_icon.Visible)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        systray_icon.Icon.Dispose();
        systray_icon.Dispose();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The right answer has already been given. But you must also provide a delay, for example with a timer. Only then the application can still remove the icon in the background.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer mCloseAppTimer;
private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    notifyIcon.Visible = false; notifyIcon.Dispose; 
    mCloseAppTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); 
    mCloseAppTimer.Interval = 100; 
    mCloseAppTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnCloseAppTimerTick); 
} 
private void OnCloseAppTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Environment.Exit(0); // other exit codes are also possible 
}
```

Comment: Surely the use of a timer is an overkill - wouldn't Thread.Sleep(1000), do the same thing? You could even use it within a new thread so it doesn't 'pause' any GUI ect