# Unable to Dispose Control (NotifyIcon)

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, notifyicon

In my homework application; I am required to create an application where I am also required to use a NotifyIcon.

I'm facing a problem where I cannot understand why the Code never reaches the Dispose Event.

I'm implementing "IDisposable"; (in order to be able to call Dispose on the NotifyIcon).
However, after adding a breakpoint in the dispose event; I can see that I cannot reach it.
I can't really understand the reason why it doesn't get there.

I'm currently following this thread to help me out with this control:
[NotifyIcon remains in Tray even after application closing but disappears on Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723843/notifyicon-remains-in-tray-even-after-application-closing-but-disappears-on-mous)

Can anyone help me understanding the reason why this happens or what am I missing?

**My Class Code:**

```
    private NotifyIcon trayIcon;

    public void CreateTrayIcon()
    {
        if (trayIcon == null) { trayIcon = new NotifyIcon(); }
        trayIcon.Text = "My Tray Application";
        trayIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.AppIcon;
        trayIcon.Disposed += TrayIcon_Disposed;

        trayIcon.Visible = true;
    }

    private void TrayIcon_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e) // Unreacheable Code
    {
        if (trayIcon != null) 
        {
            trayIcon.Visible = false;
            trayIcon = null;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool Disposing)
    {
        if (Disposing)
        {
           trayIcon.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

And Call NotifyIcon Dispose on Main Form; Form_ClosingEvent

```
private void Form_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    trayIcon.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: And where is this whole class used? There is no automatism that calls a `Dispose` method just because you implemented it. Please show the code where the instance of your class is disposed.

Comment: Sorry René; 
I completely forgot to add the part of code where I call Dispose.
Already updated my question.
I call Dispose from: Main Form on FormClosing Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

The reason behind my problem; was literally distraction.
I was assuming the FormClosing Event was subscribed, (honestly: I was sure I had it subscribed. I must have made some kind of roll back and removed it by mistake).

**Solution:** Just needed to check that the event was subscribed.